# Method not printing ArrayList content correctly

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to print out the content of my `ArrayList` however it doesn't print out correctly. More specifically it is the `getAccountSaldo` in `CustomerRegister` that is not returning the correct value (if I wanna print out for example a different account).

Here is my code:

Class Account

```
public class Account {

private Customer customer;
private String nbr;
private double saldo;

public void setNbr(String nbr){
    this.nbr = nbr;
}

public String getNbr(){
    return nbr;
}

public void setSaldo(double saldo){
    this.saldo = saldo;
}

public double getSaldo(){
    return saldo;
}

public void setCustomer(Customer customer){
    this.customer = customer;
}

public Customer getCustomer(){
    return customer;
}

public void withdraw(double amount){
    saldo -= amount;
}

public void deposit(double amount){
    saldo += amount;
}



}
```

Class Customer

```
public class Customer {

private String nbr;
private String namn;

private ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();

public void setNbr(String nbr){
    this.nbr = nbr;
}

public String getNbr(){
    return nbr;
}

public void setNamn(String namn){
    this.namn = namn;
}

public String getNamn(){
    return namn;
}

public void setAccounts(ArrayList<Account> accounts){
    this.accounts = accounts;
}

public ArrayList<Account> getAccounts(){
    return accounts;
}

public void add(Account account){
    accounts.add(account);
}

public Account find(String nbr){
    for(Account a : accounts){
        if(nbr == a.getNbr()){
            return a;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Class CustomerRegister

```
public class CustomerRegister {

private ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

public void setCustomers(ArrayList<Customer> customers){
    this.customers = customers;
}

public ArrayList<Customer> getCustomers(){
    return customers;
}

public void add(Customer k){
    customers.add(k);
}

public Customer find(String nr){
    for (Customer b : customers){
        if (nr == b.getNbr()){
            return b;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public ArrayList<Account> printAccounts(String customerNbr){
    Customer l = find(customerNbr);
    if (l != null){
        return l.getAccounts();
    }
    return null;
}

// CAN'T SOLVE THIS
public Double getAccountSaldo(String customerNbr, String accountNbr) {
    double balance = 0;
    Customer custNbr = find(customerNbr);
    // Shouldn't it be "Account acctNbr = find(accountNbr);" here? 
    // Problem is I can't access that method in this class...

    if(custNbr != null){
    for (Account x : printAccounts(customerNbr)) {
        if (accountNbr == x.getNbr()) {
            balance += x.getSaldo();
        }
        return balance;
    }
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Class demo:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args){

    CustomerRegister r1 = new CustomerRegister();
    ArrayList<Account> listOfAccounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
    ArrayList<Customer> listOfCustomers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

    Customer c = new Customer();
    c.setNbr("1");
    c.setNamn("Adam Schinn");

    Account a = new Account();
    a.setNbr("Konto 1");
    a.setSaldo(2200);
    a.setCustomer(c);

    Account b = new Account();
    b.setNbr("Konto 2");
    b.setSaldo(2000);
    b.setCustomer(c);

    listOfCustomers.add(c);
    listOfAccounts.add(a);
    listOfAccounts.add(b);

    c.setAccounts(listOfAccounts);
    r1.add(c);

    r1.setCustomers(listOfCustomers);

    for(Account temp : r1.printAccounts("1")){
        System.out.println(temp.getNbr() + " Balance: " + temp.getSaldo() + "kr ");
    }

    for(Customer temp : r1.getCustomers()){
        System.out.println("Nr: " + temp.getNbr() + " Namn: " + temp.getNamn());
    }

    // CAN'T SOLVE THIS
    // If I write "Konto 2" instead of "Konto 1" it prints "0.0"
    System.out.println(r1.getAccountSaldo("1", "Konto 1"));


}
}
```

Print out

```
Konto 1 Balance: 2200.0kr 
Konto 2 Balance: 2000.0kr 
Nr: 1 Namn: Adam Schinn
2200.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compare strings using **==** operator, this will not check equality for content instead it check the address of two strings.
Also the return statement was not at correct position.
I have made few changes to your function, have a try with that :

```
public Double getAccountSaldo(String customerNbr, String accountNbr) {
    double balance = 0;
    Customer custNbr = find(customerNbr);
    // Shouldn't it be "Account acctNbr = find(accountNbr);" here? 
    // Problem is I can't access that method in this class...

    if(custNbr != null){
    for (Account x : printAccounts(customerNbr)) {
        if (accountNbr.equals(x.getNbr())) {
            balance += x.getSaldo();

        }        
    }
    }
    return balance;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any suggested improvements for my code (particularly demo class)? To elaborate: any way I don't have to create the lists in demo class and simply use the add method? (I am a total newb and just learning ArrayLists)

Comment: Just one suggestion, you still have wrong string comparison in your classes, just do that correct and your application will work as required. If you want to play more then change you demo class to take some input from user and then proceed accordingly.